# Can anyone explain why to we need to scale in SpriteKit?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I'm trying to learn how to develop IOS games, and i just can't get it why do i see in most of the tutorials setScale(0.5) for an SKSpriteNode, mostly for the ground and stuff like that.

But i don't understand why is that scaling, why not make the size what i want in the first place and not scale down? And how that affects per devices?
I see that a lot but can't figure that out.

Thank you,
Erez

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scale is useful for several things. The simple case would be you need a different size of an existing asset. For example say you need thumbnails of an existing asset. You can scale it down instead of having a smaller version of that asset. In general you want to scale down versus scale up. But scaling up can work at certain times.

Now a more complicated case. Animation or special effects. While most people probably use flip book style animations, mixing this with scale can have benefits. Take a bouncing ball. When a ball bounces, it compresses (scale Y). You can either represent this as artwork, or you can use scale. You could also have an enemy "jump out" from an area. You may do this by having him very small and behind a bush. As he is "jumping out" you are scaling him up to 100% (or maybe even more).

These are just a few examples of the usefulness of scale.

Answer (score 0):

The `setScale` function sets the `xScale` and `yScale` properties of the node.

The `xScale` property scales the width of the node and all of its descendants. The scale value affects how a node’s frame is calculated, its hit test area, how it is drawn, and other similar characteristics. The default value is 1.0.

The `yScale` property scales the height of the node and all of its descendants. The scale value affects how a node’s frame is calculated, its hit test area, how it is drawn, and other similar characteristics. The default value is 1.0.

Reference from the Apple [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/sknode/1483126-setscale).

Comment: I've read the manual, and thank you for your alaborate answer, but it still doesn't answer my question, why not use always scale 1.0 with correct sizes, why do a big picture and scale it to 0.5 permanently? 10x

Comment: @Erez, "The scale value affects how a node’s frame is calculated, its hit test area, how it is drawn, and other similar characteristics." If you set it to 0.5 it´s the half test area, half hit test etc. Create to sprites and setValue to 0.5 to one and 1.0 to the other and you´ll see it.

Comment: Rashwan:  I think he is looking at a tutorial or an older setup that used set scale the incorrect way.  @Erez, The person who designed the tutorial or template was not using it the correct way,  they were trying to quickly set up a game scene using the view, which ended up being the device size, and scale it down to support both iphone and ipad.  This is not how you want to setup your project.

Comment: Ah ok @Knight0fDragon :) thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @knight0fdragon i see that many times, so what is the right way? where can i find a good tutorial that does that in the right way? 10x

Comment: @RashwanL, no problem, probably a tutorial that used `GameSize(size:)` with `scaleMode aspectFill`, and expects the user to divide everything (Oy, the horror)

Comment: no aspectFill, just the images and then make the size by the image and then scale it with setScale, and it is not one tutorial but many

Comment: @Erez  I have a sprite kit chatroom on here, but I have no idea how to invite you,  if you join it ill explain there